# Adding toFixed To Existing Math.abs Function

Tags: javascript, math, tofixed

I have a function I've been playing around with to try and display certain larger cardinal numbers with a text suffix. However I would like to expand upon it so that I can call toFixed to omit all decimals (toFixed(0)). I have tried all possible combinations and on the variable itself but I can't seem to get it to work...

The function I have that I want no decimals to display is:

```
function cardinalNumbers(numericalValue) {
// Twenty Four Zeroes For Septillions.

return Math.abs(Number(numericalValue)) >= 1.0e+24
   ? Math.abs(Number(numericalValue)) / 1.0e+24 + "S"

   // Twnty One Zeroes For Sextillions.
   : Math.abs(Number(numericalValue)) >= 1.0e+21
   ? Math.abs(Number(numericalValue)) / 1.0e+21 + "s"

   // Eighteen Zeroes For Quintillions.
   : Math.abs(Number(numericalValue)) >= 1.0e+18
   ? Math.abs(Number(numericalValue)) / 1.0e+18 + "Q"

   // Fifteen Zeroes For Quadrillion.
   : Math.abs(Number(numericalValue)) >= 1.0e+15
   ? Math.abs(Number(numericalValue)) / 1.0e+15 + "q"

   // Twelve Zeroes For Trillions.
   : Math.abs(Number(numericalValue)) >= 1.0e+12
   ? Math.abs(Number(numericalValue)) / 1.0e+12 + "T" 

   // Nine Zeroes For Billions.
   : Math.abs(Number(numericalValue)) >= 1.0e+9
   ? Math.abs(Number(numericalValue)) / 1.0e+9 + "B"

   // Six Zeroes For Millions.
   : Math.abs(Number(numericalValue)) >= 1.0e+6
   ? Math.abs(Number(numericalValue)) / 1.0e+6 + "M"

   // Three Zeroes For Thousands.
   : Math.abs(Number(numericalValue)) >= 1.0e+3
   ? Math.abs(Number(numericalValue)) / 1.0e+3 + "K"

   : Math.abs(Number(numericalValue));
}
```

An example would be 227155515434853440 formats as 227q.

Comment: Woah, why don't you `var x = Math.abs(Number(numericalValue));` and then use `x`? Would make it much more readable. Also I'd use an array with those, loop (or `some`) and break when I pass the threshold.

Comment: The problem is I already use other functions that end up making things really complicated, such as:

`resourceBuildingCost = Math.ceil(resourceBaseCost * Math.pow(resourceCostModifier, resourceBuildingLevel));`

So I end up trying to "make ends meet" as I learn javascript more fluently. Right now things work, complicated as they may be, in time I am sure I will go back and re-write and simplify once I fully understand what I am doing! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to call `.toFixed(0)` at every point where a value is being returned and maybe a variable like Bartek suggested:

```
function cardinalNumbers(numericalValue) {

    var x = Math.abs(Number(numericalValue));
    // Twenty Four Zeroes For Septillions.
    return x >= 1.0e+24
    ? (x / 1.0e+24).toFixed(0) + "S"

    // Twnty One Zeroes For Sextillions.
    : x >= 1.0e+21
    ? (x / 1.0e+21).toFixed(0) + "s"

    // Eighteen Zeroes For Quintillions.
    : x >= 1.0e+18
    ? (x / 1.0e+18).toFixed(0) + "Q"

    // Fifteen Zeroes For Quadrillion.
    : x >= 1.0e+15
    ? (x / 1.0e+15).toFixed(0) + "q"

    // Twelve Zeroes For Trillions.
    : x >= 1.0e+12
    ? (x / 1.0e+12).toFixed(0) + "T" 

    // Nine Zeroes For Billions.
    : x >= 1.0e+9
    ? (x / 1.0e+9).toFixed(0) + "B"

    // Six Zeroes For Millions.
    : x >= 1.0e+6
    ? (x / 1.0e+6).toFixed(0) + "M"

    // Three Zeroes For Thousands.
    : x >= 1.0e+3
    ? (x / 1.0e+3).toFixed(0) + "K"

    : x.toFixed(0);
}
```

Or if you can use an array and want to use the same construct, you could use `.toFixed(0)` once. But I don't like using ternary operators for that much branching, so I would rather use if-elseif-else blocks:

```
function cardinalNumbers(numericalValue) {
    var result = [];
    var x = Math.abs(Number(numericalValue));
    if (x >= 1.0e+24) {
        // Twenty Four Zeroes For Septillions.
        result = [x / 1.0e+24, "S"];
    } else if (x >= 1.0e+21) {
        // Twenty One Zeroes For Sextillions.
        result = [x / 1.0e+21, "s"];
    } else if (x >= 1.0e+18) {
        // Eighteen Zeroes For Quintillions.
        result = [x / 1.0e+18, "Q"];
    } else if (x >= 1.0e+15) {
        // Fifteen Zeroes For Quadrillion.
        result = [x / 1.0e+15, "q"];
    } else if (x >= 1.0e+12) {
        // Twelve Zeroes For Trillions.
        result = [x / 1.0e+12, "T"];
    } else if (x >= 1.0e+9) {
        // Nine Zeroes For Billions.
        result = [x / 1.0e+9, "B"];
    } else if (x >= 1.0e+6) {
        // Six Zeroes For Millions.
        result = [x / 1.0e+6, "M"];
    } else if (x >= 1.0e+3) {
        // Three Zeroes For Thousands.
        result = [x / 1.0e+3, "K"];
    } else {
        result = [x, ""];
    }
    return result[0].toFixed(0) + result[1];
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for my needs, and I learnt a great deal more about variables in functions, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your original question is that you need to call `.toFixed(0)` after the division, but before adding the suffix:
`( Math.abs(Number(numericalValue)) / 1.0e+9 ).toFixed(0) + "B"`

But you keep doing the same thing.  That’s screaming for a loop of some sort.

```
function cardinalNumbers(numericalValue) {
    var suffixes = ['','K','M','B','T','q','Q','s','Q'];
    var x = Math.abs(Number(numericalValue));
    var sign = numericalValue / x;
    var index = 0;
    while ( x >= 1.0e3 ) {
        x /= 1.0e3;
        index++;
    }
    x *= sign;
    return x.toFixed(0)+suffixes[index];
}
```

This will run into problems if your numbers are too big.  You'll either need to break out of the loop, or decide on some suffixes for larger numbers.

Answer (score 0):

ntg like that, ur div of x is overlapping,,, first 3 have the value of 1st, so rewrite the code

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).